# Translating 'creative by nature' / 'naturally creative' into latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation, motto

I would like to know the meaning of 'creative by nature' or 'naturally creative' in latin. According to google translater it is 'natura partum', but when translated back into english it means something else.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the confusion here stems from algorithms and double meanings. The Google Translate algorithm doesn't understand the role of 'creative' in the sentence, so it substitutes *partum*, from the verb *pario*, which means "bear, or give birth to, *to create*." When you put it into the algorithm again, this word's first two meanings are used, leading to *natural delivery.*

The correct translation here would be *naturaliter artifex*, from *naturalis* (“natural”) +‎ *-iter* (adverbial ending) and *artifex* ("artful, creative").

Comment: Though _artifex_ means "artist, creator" or "master, expert".

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. According to Oxford Latin Dictionary, it's also commonly used as an adjective.

Comment: @cnread I notice that's true, but [it still seems](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/vocabulary/adjective/1145/) to have more to do with ability rather than creativity.

Answer (score 2):

"By nature" may be translated either with the ablative of cause *naturā* or with (what appears to be) the agent complement *a natura*. We find the latter in Cicero's *Brutus*:

> T. Torquatus T. f. et doctus vir ex Rhodia disciplina Molonis et a natura ad dicendum satis solutus atque expeditus [...]
>
> "Titus Torquatus, son of Titus, who was taught by Molo in Rhodes and by nature gifted with decent effortlessness and ease in speaking" [...]

The ablative of cause is attested in Seneca the Younger's *De ira*, Liber III:

> Omnes sensus perducendi sunt ad firmitatem; naturā patientes sunt [...]
>
> "All senses must be directed to firmness; they are enduring by nature" [...]

I couldn't find a single word suitable enough for "creative". "Creativity" itself doesn't have a perfect analogue (*imaginatio* comes close).

However  we may use a construction similar to what we see in Cicero: ***ad inveniendum expeditus***. We may specifically translate it as "full of inventive", so "creative". More literally, it indicates "ease in inventing, imagining".

In conclusion, two possible translations are ***Ad inveniendum naturā expĕdītus*** and ***A natura ad inveniendum expĕdītus***. I personally prefer the former, I would choose the latter if the qualities were more than one (like in Cicero's case).

Answer (score 1):

The adjective *praeditus* is often used to speak of one's 'natural gifts' or endowments: courage, criminality, wisdom, eloquence, self-control, talent, and so on – even limbs.

It's paired with some noun to denote the thing with which one is endowed. That noun is typically modified by its own adjective. Apuleius, Lucretius, and Cicero are especially fond of this word.

In Lucretius's *De rerum natura*, a phrase that recurs several times is 'endowed with such-and-such a nature.' The phrase is used to describe the way something naturally/intrinsically is – for example, in book 1, line 236:

> *inmortali sunt natura praedita certe*,
>   'certainly, they are endowed with an immortal nature'

The question is, which adjective should be used to make Lucretius's phrase mean 'endowed with a creative nature'? As Vincenzo Oliva has noted in his answer, there isn't really a classical Latin word for 'creative' in our modern sense.

I'll make three suggestions. Ultimately, it's down to you to choose the one that best captures your own conception of the word 'creative' and that best suits what you intend to use the phrase for.

1. **Sollers:** The *Oxford Latin dictionary* defines this adjective as 'full of devices or expedients, clever, skilled, ingenious, resourceful.' Although 'skilled' is in that list of definitions, the other definitions suggest that the word goes beyond mere physical abilities, to the way that those abilities are exercised.

   *Sollers* and related words can be used to describe ingeniousness or cleverness ('creativity') in various practices (e.g., speaking, warfare, or architecture) and also in the plastic and performing arts – for example:

   - Horace, *Ars poetica* 407:

     > *Musa lyrae sollers*
     >   'the Muse skilled/ingenious at the lyre'
   - Horace, *Carmina* 4.8.7-8:

     > *hic saxo, liquidis ille coloribus / sollers nunc hominem ponere, nunc deum*
     >   'the latter man (Scopas) skilled/ingenious at depicting now a human, now a god in stone, the former (Parrhasius) at depicting them in liquid colors'

   In this case, the phrase would be ***sollertī nātūrā praeditus***, 'endowed with an ingenious nature.'
2. **Artifex:** This noun/adjective was used in user12390879's answer. Among its meanings are 'A craftsman in one of the fine arts, a sculptor, painter or the like, an artist'; 'An actor, musician or dancer (on the stage or elsewhere), and artist, performer'; and 'A maker, creator, producer; the author (of a book).'

   The advantages of this word are that it's strongly linked to the plastic and performing arts, and the word 'art' is clearly recognizable in it. Both these facts may be significant if you're thinking specifically in terms of artistic creativity.

   In this case, the phrase would be ***artificī nātūrā praeditus***, 'endowed with an artistic nature.'
3. **Inventrix:** This was inspired by Vincenzo Oliva's answer, though it involves a bit of license, because the feminine noun *inventrix* is being used as a feminine adjective. Still, such a thing is done often enough in Latin literature that I feel comfortable suggesting it. The noun is based on a verb that has among its meanings 'To devise, contrive, plan'; and 'To devise for the first time, originate, discover, invent.' It's a fairly general sort of creativity.

   Of course, the advantage of *inventrix* is that the word 'invent' is clearly recognizable in it.

   In this case, the phrase would be ***inventricī nātūrā praeditus***, 'endowed with an inventive nature.'

Note that, in all three versions, if the phrase is describing a female specifically, you would replace *praeditus* with *praedita*; for a group of males only, or a mixed group of males and females, you'd use *praeditī*; and for a group of females exclusively, you'd use *praeditae*.